# Android resource compilation failed (Android Studio ver. 3.2.1)

Tags: java, android

Anyone facing this issue? Can anyone also help to resolve this?

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:/Users/alvinlee/AndroidStudioProjects/Testing/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1797: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: /Users/alvinlee/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/2b76bad4c2fb4c47c9afdc1612d6e963/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 compile --legacy \
    -o \
    /Users/alvinlee/AndroidStudioProjects/Testing/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug \
    /Users/alvinlee/AndroidStudioProjects/Testing/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the file you have been made **values.xml**

an inner element must either be a resource reference or When declaring id in resources, the body should be empty

like this:-

```
<item
    type="id"
    name="id_name" />
```